# Ebean using And in Query

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, ebean

I'm trying to make a query where I want to check if an account info is active(boolean = True) and its for that user(userid from Model). In SQL i would write like

```
Select * from mst_account where user=1 and active = 1
```

I want to do this using Ebean in play framework.

How do I write such a query using ebean.

Model is as below for user Account

```
    @Table(name="mst_user_account")

public class UserAccount extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String email="";

    public String username="";

    public String password="";

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    public Date createdOn=new Date();

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    public Date activatedOn;

    public String activationCode="";


    public Boolean activationStatus=false;

    public Boolean accountStatus=false;

    @ManyToOne
    public Roles role;



    public static Finder<Long,UserAccount> find=new Finder<Long,UserAccount>(Long.class,UserAccount.class);

    public static UserAccount findByEmail(String email){

        return UserAccount.find.where().eq("email",email).findUnique();
    }


    public static UserAccount findByUsername(String username){

        return UserAccount.find.where().eq("username",username).findUnique();

    }

    public static UserAccount findByActivationCode(String code){
        return UserAccount.find.where().eq("activationCode",code).findUnique();
    }


    public static UserAccount authenticate(String username,String password){
        return UserAccount.find.where().eq("username",username).eq("password",password).findUnique();
    }

//mod seroney to take care of display of username----
    public static UserAccount isLoggedIn() {
        String uuid = session("id");
        UserAccount user = UserAccount.find.byId(Long.parseLong(uuid));
        return user;


    }
```

Model For Account

```
@Entity
@Table(name="mst_account")
public class Account extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String firstName="";

    public String surname = "";

    public String otherName="";

    public String address="";

    public String city="";

    public String country="";

    public String mobile="";

    public String zipcode="";

    public String stateprv ="";

    public String usrtimezone ="";

    public Boolean physicalDisability =false;

    public String physicalDisabilityDesc ="";

    @OneToOne
    public ModeOfStudy modeOfStudy;

    @OneToOne
    public Campus campus;

    @OneToOne
    public CourseMst course;

    public String hschatt ="";

    public String hsgpa ="";

    public Qualifications hschyr;

    public String unvatt ="";

    public String ungpa ="";

    public Qualifications unvyr;

    public Boolean isprocessed = false;

    public Boolean isapproved = false;

    public Boolean isPosted = false;

    @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    public Date createdOn=new Date();

    @OneToOne
    public UserAccount user;
    @OneToOne
    public UserAccount isapprovedby;


    public static Finder<Long,Account> find=new Finder<Long,Account>(Long.class,Account.class);

    public static Account findByMobile(String mob){

        return Account.find.where().eq("mobile",mob).findUnique();
    }

    public static Account findByAltPhone(String phone){

        return Account.find.where().eq("alternatePhone",phone).findUnique();
    }

    public static Account findByCardNumber(String card){

        return Account.find.where().eq("cardNumber",card).findUnique();

    }


    public static Account findByUserId(Long user){

        return find.where().eq("user", user).eq("isPosted", true).findUnique();
    }


}
```

I'm trying to check if user has posted data to mst account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the following snippets in your account model. I used model name as `Account` replace your own model name.

```
public static Finder<Long,Account> find = new Finder(Long.class, Account.class);

public static Account findByUserID(int user_id){
    return find.where().eq("user", user_id).eq("active", true).findUnique();
}
```

If you are referring `UserAccount` id, then you need to change the condition by `.eq("user.id", user_id)`

```
 public static Account findByUserId(Long user){
    return find.where().eq("user.id", user).eq("isPosted", true).findUnique();
}
```

Comment: my user id is Long. Now I'm getting a error[RuntimeException: get id on [models.UserAccount] type[java.lang.Long] threw error.]
In /media/seroney/Stuff/Projects/Java/Play FrameWork/Codi/app/models/Account.java:104
101    }
102    public static Account findByUserId(Long userid){
103
104        return find.where().eq("user", userid).eq("isPosted", true).findUnique();
105    }

Comment: @Seroney Can you post your model.

Comment: added the model but its waiting for peer review

Comment: posted the models, had initially edited your answer sorry.